# How do I solve the value error in Python while doing logistic regression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sklearn-pandas

I am getting a value error in Logistic Regression.How do I solve this?

I tried dropping the survived column but still is of no use.

Input:

```
X_train=train_df.drop("Survived",axis=1)
Y_train=train_df["Survived"]
X_test=test_df.drop("PassengerId",axis=1).copy()
X_train=train_df.drop("PassengerId",axis=1).copy()
X_train.head()
Y_train.head()
X_test.head()
```

Output:

```
Pclass----Sex-----Age-------Parch-----Fare-------EMbarked
3--------- 0 -----34.5------0---------7.82-------2      
3--------- 1 -----47  ------0---------7----------0
2--------- 0 -----62  ------0---------9.68-------2
3--------- 0 -----27  ------0---------8.66-------0
3--------- 1 -----22  ------1---------12.2-------0
```

Input:

```
X_train.shape,Y_train.shape,X_test.shape
```

Output:

```
((891, 7), (891,), (418, 6))
```

input:

```
 X_train.head()
```

output:

```
Column1---Survived---Pclass----Sex----Age-----Parch----Fare----Embarked
0-------- ----0----------3-------0-----22-------0------7.25------0
1-------------1----------1-------1-----38-------0------71.2833---1
2-------------1----------3-------1-----26-------0------7.925-----0
3-------------1----------1-------1-----35-------0------53.1------0
4-------------0----------3-------0-----35-------0---- -8.05------0
```

Logistic Regression

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
acc_log = round(logreg.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
acc_log
```

Error message:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-5854ca91fc64> in <module>

      3 logreg = LogisticRegression()
      4 logreg.fit(X_train, Y_train)
----> 5 Y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
      6 acc_log = round(logreg.score(X_train, Y_train) * 100, 2)
      7 acc_log

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in predict(self, X)

        287             Predicted class label per sample.
        288         """
    --> 289         scores = self.decision_function(X)
        290         if len(scores.shape) == 1:
        291             indices = (scores > 0).astype(np.int)

c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\base.py in decision_function(self, X)

        268         if X.shape[1] != n_features:
        269             raise ValueError("X has %d features per sample; 
                   expecting %d"
    --> 270                              % (X.shape[1], n_features))
        271 
        272         scores = safe_sparse_dot(X, self.coef_.T,

ValueError: X has 6 features per sample; expecting 7
```

Comment: fit model should be built with exclusive equation as y ~ x1,x2...x6 to prevent if dataset doesnt include fit-model feature attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both X_train and Y_train should have same set of features. Your X_train is having unnecessary 'Survived' feature column in it.

Better way is to extract the necessary columns from your dataframe in this format.

```
necessary_columns = ['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'Parch', 'Fare', 'EMbarked']
X_train = train_df[necessary_columns]
Y_train = train_df["Survived"]
X_test = test_df[necessary_columns]
```